# Seeking an Application of Svarc-Milnor Lemma

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory

The Svarc-Milnor lemma is the following: Let $X$ be a length space*, and $\Gamma$ a group acting properly and cocompactly by isometries on $X$. Then $\Gamma$ is finitely generated.

This is an interesting and useful lemma in metric geometry. I would like to find a direct application of this lemma to group theory. That is to say, I would like to find an example of a space $X$ and a group $\Gamma$ which is not obviously finitely generated, where it is possible to show that $\Gamma$ has the necessary properties in order to actually prove that $\Gamma$ is finitely generated. If possible, I would like to work out a presentation for this group, but maybe this is too much to ask for.

After a few days of mulling it over, an example has eluded me. An example or reference would be wonderful!

*: A length space is defined as a space where the distance between every pair of points is equal to the infimum of the length of rectifiable curves joining the points.  Any geodesic space is a length space. For an example of a metric space which is not a length space, consider $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb R$, with the induced metric. There are no curves connecting points of $\mathbb Q$ while actually staying in $\mathbb Q$ - all curves are 'constant curves.' So there aren't even any curves joining any points for there to be any infimums to take.

Also feel free to suggest tags for this question to make it more visible.

Comment: That's not the full statement of the Svarc-Milnor lemma. It's only part of the statement, and its not the most useful part, although it does have its uses (I'll try to think of some). The rest of the Svarc-Milnor lemma says that $\Gamma$ endowed with its word metric is quasi-isometric to $X$, and this is the part that is most useful.

Comment: This is the statement from Bridson & Haefliger's book 'Metric Spaces of Non-Positive Curvature.' My apologies if the statement is incomplete, I just lifted it from there.

Comment: How obvious to you is: finite index subgroups of a finitely generated group are finitely generated?

Comment: @PaulPlummer I would call that believable, but not obvious... so... somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Well you can use Svarc-Milnor to prove it, act on the Cayley graph of the full group, and since it is finite index you will end up with a compact/finite graph. Like Mosher said, Svarc-Milnor is nice for quasi-isometry, but it is a nice benefit that the process gives you a finite generating set, and that being finitely generated is a geometric property of a group. You might see if the original Svarc or Milnor papers have what you want (since apparently they needed it to prove finite generation)

Comment: Also I would like to point out sometimes other things are used to prove similar results, I believe many proofs to prove mapping class groups of surface are finitely generated use actions on nice spaces, these actions do not satisfy S-M but use some of the same ideas

Comment: @LeeMosher QI stuff sounds like a modern (at least $\ge 1980$) redigest of the lemma. Milnor makes comparison of growth functions. I don't know about Schwartz' article I can't access. In between, other papers appeared, such as Koszul's 1965 lectures (http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr32.pdf)

Comment: @Ycor Milnor proves that the fundamental group of a closed Riemannian manifold of negative sectional curvature is of exponential growth. His proof explicitly constructs a quasi-isometry between the fundamental group and the universal covering space. True, he does not "lemma-ize" the construction of the quasi-isometry, and the lemma has since been generalized beyond the context of compact Riemanian manifolds, but historical courtesy puts his name on the lemma. I am less familiar with Schwartz' contribution and the rationale for his name on the lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example is in the paper "Morse theory and finiteness properties of groups" by Bestvina and Brady, Inventiones Mathematicae, 1997, Volume 129, Issue 3, pp 445–470.

In the paper they construct examples of finitely generated groups which are of type $FP_2$ but not finitely presented (which was an open problem for a long time). While finite generation of these groups is not the hardest part of the paper, it is not obvious. Finite generation follows from connectendness of certain complexes on which these groups are acting cocompactly (cocompactness is clear); connectedness, in turn, follows from some Morse-theoretic considerations. (The property $FP_2$ follows from acyclicity of these complexes.)

Comment: While I haven't gotten around to reading the paper in any depth yet, I do like what I see so far, and I feel your help warrants the bounty. I may leave the question open yet though, so others could see that answers are still being accepted. Nevertheless, thanks for yourhelp.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q$ be the quadratic form $X^2+Y^2+(1+\sqrt{2})Z^2$. Define $\Gamma=SO(q)(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. Then one shows that $\Gamma$ is finitely generated using its proper cocompact isometric action on the hyperbolic plane.

More generally, cocompact lattices in virtually connected Lie groups are finitely generated, by this argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Svarc-Milnor Lemma to show that $Out(F_n)$ is f.g. using its action on the spine $\mathcal{K}_n \subset \mathcal{X}_n$.

See for example in Corollary 2.6.2 of "The topology, geometry, and dynamics of free groups" by Lee Mosher